# Login-protected page is not requiring login to access

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have written this script to prevent users that haven't logged in from viewing certain pages. I have tried to get it working but no joy. I would be very grateful if  someone could tell me what wrong.

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once ("ConnectToMySql.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location:../Login/LoginForm.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please elaborate how it's not working.

Comment: Its letting me access the page without loging in.

Comment: have you checked $_SESSION to see what data it contains?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's test if the user is authenticated:

```
<?php

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); // print all the session to see if $_SESSION['username'] is set
exit;
...
```

If the user is logged, restart the browser to end the session. (You must restart the browser, it is not enough to close that tab)

If the `$_SESSION` is empty, the user is not logged in, remove the first test lines and let's see if the execution goes to the `header` function:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo "User will be redirected";
    exit;
    header("location:../Login/LoginForm.php");
}
```

If it goes ok so far, it means that the redirection is not working.
Please note that if there was any output sent, the headers can no longer be sent to the browser. If that is the case you need to check your files (also files included like `ConnectToMySql.php`) for any output. A frequent mistake is adding a blank space after closing the php tag `?>` in a configuration file and that is very hard to find and debug. A simple practice to avoid that is never put the php end tag `?>` in files containing only PHP.

Depending on these tests, you could at least find out what is not working.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply but I have been away. I have tried the your answer and it echos out  User will be restricted. I have removed the echo and exit and found that the header isn't working and that's why its not blocking the page.